# Unable to startup test. Unknown tests gets called for Robot Framework Test Execution

Tags: robotframework

I'm surprised to see this error message when executing Test Automation using RobotFramework with RED editor. Plz guide me on this issue getting rectified.

I dont have any test case called "Filter the customer". When running my suite it shows up the below error.

Note: I did the below, even then I'm having this issue.
   1. I cleaned the Project
   2. I also deleted and re-added the modified libraries.
   3. Saved all the updated files.

Error: 
[image]

The source is as below,

```
*** Setting ***
Resource   ../KCC_Automation/ResourceFiles/KCC_Resource.txt
*** Test Cases ***
Login with valid credentials
  Logon to KCC browser
  Enter User Name
  Enter Password
  Click Login
Show Customers available in Customer List Page
  Get the customer names and click them from Customer List Page
Begin the New Assessment for an opportunity
  Filter by Customer Search
Expand the customer details and begin the New Assessment
  Stop Testing
Logout of KCC
```

And the resource file is as below,

```
*** Keywords ***
Welcome1
  ${message}    say hi
  Log    ${message}
Welcome2
  ${message}    say hi    Testers
  Log    ${message}
Welcome3
  ${message}    type of    42
  Log    ${message}
Logon to KCC browser
  Open Browser  ${LOGIN URL}  ${BROWSER}
  Wait Until Page contains Element  ${UserName_Field}
Enter User Name
  Input Text  ${UserName_Field}  ${USERNAME}
  sleep  2s
Enter Password
  Input Text  ${Password_Field}  ${PASSWORD}
  sleep  2s
Click Login
  Click Element  ${LoginButton}
  sleep  5s
Get the customer names and click them from Customer List Page
  set selenium speed  5s
  wait until element is visible  ${customers_grid}
  wait until page contains element  ${customers_grid}
  sleep  3s
  @{customers}  get webelements    ${customer_list}
  ${items}  Store Texts  @{customers}
  #${items}  storeTexts  @{customers}[2]
  ${store}  get text  ${items}
  Log  ${store}
Filter by Customer Search
  set selenium speed  5s
  input text  ${Customer_Search}  ${Search_Text}
  sleep  3s
  ${Entered_text}=  get value  ${Customer_Search}
  should be equal  ${Search_Text}  ${Entered_text}  The given message is incorrect  true
Expand the customer details and begin the New Assessment
    wait until page contains element  ${customer_list}
    click element  ${customer_list}
    sleep  2s
    click element  ${opportunity-status}
    sleep  2s
    click element  ${forward_button}
    sleep  2s
    click element  ${Btn_Add_Building}
    sleep  2s
Logout of KCC
```

In the source file, I re-placed the test case name "Begin the New Assessment for an opportunity" by "filter the customers" as because earlier i named this testcase like this, executing it showing up below issue now, Is this RED editor issue?

```
[ ERROR ] Unexpected error: NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/openqa/selenium/WebElement
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
at robot.utils.importer$py.import_$32(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py:274)
at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py)
at robot.utils.importer$py._import_class_or_module$5(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py:77)
at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py)
at robot.utils.importer$py.import_class_or_module$4(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py:74)
at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py)
at robot.model.visitor$py.visit_suite$2(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py:88)
at robot.model.visitor$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.visit$19(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py:161)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py)
at robot.model.itemlist$py.visit$11(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\itemlist.py:75)
at robot.model.itemlist$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\itemlist.py)
at robot.model.visitor$py.visit_suite$2(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py:88)
at robot.model.visitor$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.visit$19(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py:161)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py)
at robot.utils.application$py._execute$10(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py:94)
at robot.utils.application$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py)
at robot.utils.application$py.execute_cli$5(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py:49)
at robot.utils.application$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py)
at runpy$py._run_code$9(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py:73)
at runpy$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py)
at runpy$py._run_module_as_main$14(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py:161)
at runpy$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 191 more
```

Comment: Some of us can't see images due to restrictions, and also, it is 1000x better to have the source code in text - not as in image. As we can try to replicate it on our own machine. Please, replace your source code image, with the actual source code...

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Please check it now, I'm having a big trouble.

Comment: The original error - no tests named - most probably came from the command to execute the suite in RED - it probably specified the test to run by name, e.g. `--test "filter the customers"', and rightfully failed, as there wasn't such case. Too bad the screenshot is cut-off at that part :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error it seems to me that you don't have the Selenium2Library loaded `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement` You can load a library by using the syntax:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
```

Please keep in mind that this library requires either a `pip install robotframework-selenium2library` or to install the [Java Port](https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/robotframework-selenium2library-java#readme) of the Selenium2Library

Although I can't be sure, I suspect that when this issue is resolved your other problem is also fixed.

Comment: The specified set up done earlier, unsure about the issue. Hence re-installed the Jython and selenium2library and re-tried, it worked successfully. Thanks Kootstra.